# C# MySQL connection to fails to connect when I lose internet

Tags: c#, mysql

I am running a C# program that connects to a local MySQL server on it's own network. It all works fine until I lose internet and then the C# will not connect to the server despite being referenced by IP (see code below).

```
 public bool IsConnect()
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (Connection == null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName))
                result = false;
            string connstring = string.Format("Server=192.168.0.254; database={0}; UID=show; password=", "");

            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
                connection.Open();
                result = true;
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        // MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        // MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What causes you to "lose internet"?

Comment: Is it because your router goes down and as a result so does your network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was about to post more info but suddenly found the answer.

Adding

skip-name-resolve

To my.cnf stops MySQL trying to resolve clients via DNS which was causing my problem

Comment: You should get exception if your databasename is empty I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking your databaseName.

```
public bool IsConnect()
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (Connection == null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName))
                result = false;
            string connstring = string.Format("Server=192.168.0.254; database={0}; UID=show; password=", "");

            try
            {
            //Database name is not empty 
            if(result)
                {
                connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
                connection.Open();
                result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        // MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        // MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```